# How to share an xCode .app product with others

Tags: xcode

I built a pretty simple application in xCode and want to share it with someone else's computer which does not run xCode. It's a simple print to console app. How do I share it with them without going through iTunesconnect (seems like a waste).

Is there a way to send them a package they can install and run the app? Send them the app itself? Download it from github?

I'm flexible on ways to share it but don't want to put xCode on her comp.

I've built it for archiving and signed it (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Organizer->Archives. You can "Export Developer ID-signed" to save a .pkg. That will need you to have a certificate (private key) as "Developer-ID Application" and "Developer-ID Installer". Go to developer.apple.com to get that certificates. That way, app can be installed on any mac that permits installation of apps from App Store and Identified Developers.

If you don't sign the app, you can export as Application or Installer. But users will have to enable the installation of any app in Settings->Security.

Comment: I can't figure out how to export without signing. Can you explain that? When I am in my organizer, all I see is "Distribute" and then you have to sign it to do anything else.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about a Mac (OS X) App. Right? Then, click on "Distribute..." and a panel is open with three options: "Summit to App Store.."; "Export Developer-ID Signed" and "Export as.."